# Conditional expectation of sum of two uniform random variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, expected-value

I want to compute the conditional expectation of the sum of two independent uniform random variables, with two conditions. Is there anything wrong with my approach below?

Formally, let $X,Y$ both be independent draws from $U(0,1)$. I want the expectation of $X+Y$, conditional on $X\ge c_1$, where $c_1$ is a constant, and conditional on $X+Y\ge c_2 \iff Y\ge c_2-X$, where $c_2$ is another constant.

Edit: Via double integrals:
$$E[X+Y|X\ge c_1,X+Y\ge c_2]=\frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x+y) 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
$$=\frac{\int_{c_1}^1 \int_0^1 (x+y) 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
$$=\frac{\int_{c_1}^1 \int_{\max\{0,c_2-x\}}^1 (x+y) dy dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
$$=\frac{\int_{c_1}^1 \left[ xy+y^2/2\right]_{\max\{0,c_2-x\}}^1 dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
$$=\frac{\int_{c_1}^1 x(1-\max\{0,c_2-x\})+\frac{1-\max\{0,c_2-x\}^2}{2} dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
Now, for $x\ge c_2$, $\max\{0,c_2-x\}=0$, and $\max\{0,c_2-x\}=c_2-x$ otherwise. Hence, for $c_2> c_1$,
$$=\frac{\int_{c_1}^{c_2} x(1-c_2+x)+\frac{1-(c_2-x)^2}{2} dx+\int_{c_2}^1 x+1/2 dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
$$=\frac{\left[ \frac{(1-c_2)x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x(1-c_2^2)}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{c_2x^2}{2} \right]_{c_1}^{c_2}+\left[ \frac{x^2+x}{2} \right]_{c_2}^1}{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{x\ge c_1\}\cdot 1\{x+y\ge c_2\} dy dx}$$
where I will not simplify the numerator further since it will remain relatively messy, with cubic terms for $c_1$ and $c_2$. Instead of integrating in the denominator, I use basic geometry to calculate the area, which for $c_2>c_1$ is a square minus a triangle. Hence,
$$=\frac{\left[ \frac{(1-c_2)x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x(1-c_2^2)}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{c_2x^2}{2} \right]_{c_1}^{c_2}+1-\frac{c_2^2+c_2}{2}}{1-c_1+c_1c_2-\frac{c_1^2+c_2^2}{2}}.$$
Now, for $c_1,c_2=0$, the two conditions become non-binding, and this expression simplifies to 1, which is the correct unconditional expectation.

Is this approach correct, and can you spot any mistakes in the computations?

Comment: The lower limit of $c_2-x$ looks suspicious. When $c_1=c_2=0$, is the expectation really a double integral over an area including negative $y$-values?

Comment: You are right that limit should be 0 when $c_2=0$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what your double integral is supposed to do. Why aren’t you just finding the average $x+y$ value over the two-dimensional set of $(x,y)$ values satisfying your restrictions? I don’t understand the second reciprocal in the integral or the lower limit. Try drawing in the 2D plane the set of $(x,y)$ values that meet your restrictions.

Comment: Well, the integrals are exactly supposed to do that, finding the average $x+y$ subject to the restrictions. Any ideas on how to improve those integration limits?

Comment: tl;dr: The integral doesn’t do what it’s “supposed to do.” The average of $x+y$ is the integral of $x+y$ divided by a constant (the area of the region of integration). Your area of integration goes below the $y$-axis (so includes spurious values of $y$, and I don’t see why the integral has the term $1\frac 1-c_2+x$. As I said before, **draw the region in a 2D plane** and set up an integral over that region. Then compute $\iint_R x+y \,dR \over \iint_R\,dR$. I don’t think you’ll have the same limits as you now have, nor will you have anything but $dx$, $dy$, and $x+y$ within either integral.

Comment: I gave it a new try with the approach you advocate above. Does it make sense now? Any mistakes you can spot?

Comment: The approach and most of it looks fine — you’re definitely on the right track. However, I think the lower limit of $\int_{\max\{0,c_2-x\}}^1$ should be $\min(1,\max(0,c_2-x))$. For example, sketch the region of possible $(x,y)$ in the case $c_1=0.1, c_2=1.2$. This is surprisingly tricky to do in general!

Comment: You are right. Thanks! If you want you can put this comment as answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving comment to answer as OP suggested.)

The approach and most of it looks fine — you’re definitely on the right track. However, I think the lower limit of $\int^1_{\max(0,c_2-x)}$ should be $\min(1,\max(0,c_2-x))$. For example, sketch the region of possible $(x,y)$ in the case $c_1=0.1,c_2=1.2$. This is surprisingly tricky to do in general!